# Counting resticted partitions of a multiset with additional restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-partitions

Say I have some multiset of integers, for example $M1=\{6,6,4,4,4,2,2\}$.

I have a second multiset that consists of some set of valid sums derived from picking without replacement from $M1$, say for example $M2=\{16,8,4\}$

I'd like to count the number of ways that $M2$ can be formed from $M1$. In the simple example above, the valid picks are

$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{2,2,6,6\} & \{4,4\} & \{4\} \\
 \{2,4,4,6\} & \{2,6\} & \{4\} \\
 \{4,6,6\} & \{2,2,4\} & \{4\} \\
 \{4,6,6\} & \{4,4\} & \{2,2\} \\
\end{array}
$

So the desired result is $4$.

I'm currently doing this algorithmically by getting the integer partitions of each element in $M2$ restricted to members of $M1$, then eliminating invalid ones, then doing a cartesian product of those sets, and eliminating those that are invalid (e.g., tally of elements does not match that of $M1$).

Obviously, this gets inefficient quickly.

Is there some combinatorial structure that enumerates this kind of thing? I poked through my copy of *Andrews*' and searched via Google scholar and came up blank.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could do this recursively.

So starting with $M1$, there are only two ways of getting elements to add up to $4$: $\{2,2\}$ and $\{4\}$.

From $M1\text{\\}   \{2,2\}=\{6,6,4,4,4\}$ there is one way of getting elements to add up to $8$: $\{4,4\}$.  From $M1\text{\\}   \{2,2,4,4\}=\{6,6,4\}$ there is one way of getting elements to add up to $16$.

From $M1\text{\\}   \{4\}=\{6,6,4,4,2,2\}$ there are three ways of getting elements to add up to $8$: $\{2,2,4\}$, $\{2,6\}$, $\{4,4\}$. From each of what remains there is one way of getting elements to add up to $16$.

Hence your four examples.

Just repeat doing this. You already have to deduplicate when $M1$ has repeated elements, and you may need to do so when $M2$ does.  My guess is that it may be easier to take the smaller elements of $M2$ as early targets, though no doubt there are particular examples where the reverse is true.